# How can I create a view of different entity types with common sorting?

Tags: views, entities, 9

Both, profiles and nodes (of one spec. nodetype) have the same taxonomy attached. (Using the profile module).
How to create a view of both together, profiles and nodes (of this type) to show as a result both sorted together (date created desc)?
Duplicate results with same nid must be filtered out (DISTINCT is not working in D8/9).

Part 2 of question:
Both, profiles and nodes (of one spec. nodetype) have a geolocation field (geolocation module) that contains coordinates (lat, long).
(In a view it is possible to do proximity sorting the result if it is a view of only nodes).
In this view profiles AND nodes (two different entity types) should be sorted together, sort order: proximity asc.

Is there a way to get this work if combining two different entity types in one view in Drupal 8/9?
How?

Comment: Views does not support queries across entity types.  You can A) redesign your site so that the fields you need to query are all in the same entity type so that you can keep using Views or B) use Solr with facets, which can do this but requires a Solr server + much more config.

Comment: "Queries across entity types" - isn't this possible with some extra code in a custom module? The goal should be: Make a view in Drupal 8/9 and do only some correction or adjustment of SQL query using the right hook functions.

Second point is: Isn't there any module that extends Drupal Views in order to be able to make queries across entity types?

Third point: 
If using Search API (database server, index over 2 entity types) this works in some easy cases. 
But I can not solve part 2 of my question above: The proximity field isn't available if using a view over the created search index.

Comment: Still searching a solution.

Comment: No, Views is not designed to allow you to query arbitrary types together.  This is because Views is showing you tons of options for the entity type it is querying; if it had to account for multiple types and the potential conflicts between them (what if you try to sort three types of entities by a field that only one of them has? etc.), it would probably become a buggy mess.  If you want to use Views, you need to carefully plan your entity types/fields in the design stage.  (Or redesign your site when it's half built-- I've had to do that too .)

Comment: But I am using the Profile Module. I think it is not easy to rewrite all the functionality of profile module to do the same things with a content type instead a entity called "profile".

Since Drupal 7 entities are getting more and more popular, a lot of things in Drupal 8/9 are using own entity types and there are modules like ECK to help creating new entities.

So there MUST be a solution to deal with all this entities, also in Views or Views with an additional module or additional custom code. 

I am sure, there must be a solution. We must find out which..

Comment: Well, if you're sure it's out there, I guess I must be totally wrong and not know what I'm talking about.  But think about this-- content entities are revisionable.  User entities + taxonomy term entities are not.  Content entities have author information; taxonomy entities do not.  If you were mixing multiple entity types in a Views query, what is Views supposed to do if, for example, you filter by author, which nodes have but users and terms don't?

Comment: The solution is to either redesign how you lay out your fields or use entity references in a clever way-- you can use one base entity to reference the others, and then filter that base entity.  But if you don't plan carefully, this will become a very difficult to maintain mess.

Comment: Entities are very important to Drupal since Drupal 7. Nobody should redesign - everybody should help to find a solution which anybody could need.